# Random slug url for friendly id gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

Has anyone ever used random_slug (https://github.com/josei/random_slug) for friendly_id? It was last updated 5 years ago so I'm not sure if it's a waste of time to try it out or even if there is a better solution?

Basically I have friendly_id working in terms of it picks up the title of my posts and I have a scope so those posts are unique to the user, but I would very much like those posts to be a randomly generated URL something similar to YouTube URL's I suppose -- is this possible with friendly ID or am I going about this the wrong way and is there something else that would make my life 100x easier?

Comment: Why dnt u use just for slug -> `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(TEXT GOES HERE)[0..8]`

Comment: Is there anywhere I can read more about this? I'm new and trying to learn through a project. Thanks for your help!

Comment: u wanna slug your post url ?

Comment: Yeah, so for example - posts/(random unique slug) for each post generated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That plugin won't work, at least not by itself.  It was designed as a rails 2 plugin which are incompatible with today's gems - but if you look at it's lib, ALL its doing is generating a random string, which as was pointed out in comment you can do using an SHA1 digest.  I like secure random. (same concept)

You model would look something like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :generated_slug, use: :slugged
  def generated_slug
    require 'securerandom' 
    @random_slug ||= persisted? ? friendly_id : SecureRandom.hex(15) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'll read more about this now -- thanks to both yourself and 7urkm3n!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way, passing `title` and `id` of each post, it will generate you new uniq slug even the `title` will be same, cause of passing extra `id` of post.

Make sure use your own column name `title` or smth else...

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slugging, use: [:slugged, :history, :finders]

    def slugging
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("#{title} #{id}")[0..8]
    end
end
```